# UIViewController's UIView autoresizing subviews not checked after restart of Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, xcode4.6, autoresizingmask

I have a UIViewController in an iPad storyboard (no autolayout).
For the UIView of that UIViewController, I checked autoresize subviews. If I run that in the simulator (iOS 5 and iOS 6), the subviews don't get autoresized. Even stranger is, that if I close the project and Xcode and relaunch both, the checkbox "autoresize subviews" isn't checked anymore.
That happens just on the iPad storyboard. The storyboard for iPhone (no autolayout too) doesn't have any problems at all.

Did someone see a similar behavior or does someone know how to fix that?

Thank you very much for your help

Linard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a very strange bug...

I have just dragged and dropped a new UIViewController with a UIView and copied the old objects in the new UIView.
Now it works!

I hope this post will save someone in the future a lot of time

Linard